# ThisWorkbook vs opened_workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

What is the difference between `ThisWorkbook` and `opened_workbook`?

I only ask because I am looking through some of my old code and I am seeing both being used, I am attempting to clean up some of this code.

As far as I know `ThisWorkbook` will always dictate the workbook in which the script is being run in, and `opened_workbook` is the workbook that is at the forefront? Am I wrong here?

I'd like to know not only if I'm right or wrong, but where both should be used, because I have a feeling I should be using `ThisWorkbook` instead of `opened_workbook` in my case.

Thanks in advance for trying to help me understand here.

Comment: what version is this?! your right about `ThisWorkbook`, but I know `opened_Workbook` only as `ActiveWorkbook` - could it be a variable of your own?

Comment: It was when I was getting help with code in the past, you may be right, but I'm glad it wasn't me going a bit crazy here... I'll be looking more into it.

Comment: Fairly sure `opened_workbook` must be a custom variable. I have never come across it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ThisWorkbook** is a variable that represents an Application-object.

**opened_workbook** must be a variable.